# How do I change the background color of a checkbox for just *one* checkbox?

Tags: html

I would like to have a simple piece of code that changes the background color of a checkbox when *unchecked*.

I tried

```
<form>
<input type=checkbox style="background: rgb(0, 255, 0) none repeat scroll 0%; color: rgb(0, 0, 255);">
</form>
```

but that doesn't work.

please note that while there are related questions to this, my question differs in:

1. I am interested in having different colors to different checkboxes on the same page.
2. I am interested in just applying a "style" tag to the input tag to get the desired result.

I don't mind adding some CSS preamble if needed.

Answer (score 0):

The checkbox doesn't have a background color, each browser renders it's own default version of these elements. Checkboxes and radio button are a bit difficult to control.

One common solution to this is to lay another element over the top of the checkbox/radio element

rather than pasting lots of code here the link below might be more helpful

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp

there are many different techniques but this one is a good starting point.

(edit: on point 2 it is not possible to do this)